# How to store <TR> id value in array, when I toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am toggling `'tr.subCategory1'`and its siblings `.RegText`. at the same time I am trying to store its ids in the array like this `list_Visible_Ids[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).css('display') != 'none' ? 1 : null;` (When I collapsed I need store `'null'` in array at its id place, If I expand I need store I need store `1` at its id place). But everytime `alert($(this).css('display'))` showing `block`. How can I handle this?. So When I collapsed or expanded it is storing `1` only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       $('tr[@class^=RegText]').hide().children('td');

        list_Visible_Ids = [];
        var idsString, idsArray;

        idsString = $('#myVisibleRows').val();
        idsArray = idsString.split(',');

        $.each(idsArray, function() {
            if (this != "" || this != null) {
                $('#' + this).siblings('.RegText').toggle();
                list_Visible_Ids[this] = 1;
            }
        });
        $('tr.subCategory1')
        .css("cursor", "pointer")
        .attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function() {
             $(this).siblings('.RegText').toggle();
             $(this).siblings('.VolumeRegText').toggle();
             //alert($(this).css('display'))
            list_Visible_Ids[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).css('display') != 'none' ? 1 : null;

        });

        $('#form1').submit(function() {

            idsString = '';
            for (var index in list_Visible_Ids) {
                idsString += (idsString != '' ? ',' : '') + index;
            }

            $('#myVisibleRows').val(idsString);
            form1.submit();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't toggling the `tr` itself, only its siblings (with class `.RegText` and `.VolumeRegText`). You therefore have to check if these are visible when you are storing the state in the array. For this you can use `.is(":hidden")` on one of the siblings. The click function would then look like this

```
$('tr.subCategory1')
.css("cursor", "pointer")
.attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")
.click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.RegText').toggle();
    var isHidden = $(this).siblings('.VolumeRegText').toggle().is(':hidden');
    list_Visible_Ids[$(this).attr('id')] = !isHidden ? 1 : null;
});
```

---

There is also a lot to comment on the rest of the code. In

```
$('tr[@class^=RegText]').hide().children('td');
```

skip the `.children('td')`, as you aren't using this selection.

---

`list_Visible_Ids = [];` should be declared using `var`.

---

Looping through `idsArray`, you are checking `this != "" || this != null)`, which should be using `&&` instead of `||`.

```
$.each(idsArray, function() {
    if (this != "" && this != null) {
        $('#' + this).siblings('.RegText').toggle();
        list_Visible_Ids[this] = 1;
    }
});
```

There's also really no point in using the `$.each()` function instead of a regular JavaScript for-loop

---

It also seems you are using an old version of jQuery, since using the `@` in selectors was deprecated in [version 1.3](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3).

Comment: Thanks Simen, you said @ in selectors was deprecated. How can I replace in my code for 1.3 or 1.4 version.?

Comment: Just remove the @ and it'll work like before. You should probably look through the changelog to see if anything else depricated is being used, too